# How to repair chipped glass

Tags: glass, table

My tabletop glass corner was chipped about 1 square cm in area. How can i reattach this chip to glass so there is no trace of breakage.

I am looking for a cheaper and best approach.

Comment: I'd suggest replacing it with tempered glass.

Comment: @DA01 why do you suggest that?

Comment: I have kids. I wouldn't trust having a non-tempered glass table top in our house. :)

Comment: No trace at all, or trace that will not be seen without a close look? Because this makes a big difference.

Comment: @Mołot No trace at all

Comment: honesty is he best policy I've heard.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that replacing with tempered glass is your best option. But if you want cheap, there are other options.

I don't know about regular super glue or Krazy glue. It would probably work fine. Loctite makes a super glue specifically for glass.

I used to work for an art glass/leaded glass company 20 years ago and we used a glue that was cured by UV light. It was nice because you could easily wipe up any excess before you set the glue. You can use a cheap UV light ($15 or less) to cure the glue. It is slower, but you can also use sunlight. It cures absolutely clear and is permanent. The bond is super strong. We used this glue to attach glass "jewels" and flat beveled glass to glass windows that we made.  Once it was cured, there was no removing it. You couldn't break the bevel off with a hammer.  I don't remember the name of it, but there are cheap UV cured glues available online and probably Lowe's/Home Depot.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't accept any trace, then cheapest way is to replace glass, simple as that.

Cyanoacrylic glue might hold it in place,  but the edge of crack will be visible if someone will look up close. And melting glass to connect it without any layer between pieces would be tricky, and it would be extremely difficult to make it as smooth as new. So difficult I'm sure no professional glassblower would even give you a price for it. Not worth it, not with cheap machine made glass you can buy.

For the table, please buy something that is hard to break, and if you can't stand minor chips, buy glass that shatters into relatively small, not too sharp pieces (tempered glass). Hey, you will be replacing it anyway, and you can't replace blood and skin so easily!

Answer (score 0):

Crazy glue. I just did it yesterday to the bottom of a vase & it's almost undetectable as well as completely water tight & I couldn't bump it back off, thankfully.

Comment: What is "Crazy glue"? Is it a cyanoacrylate adhesive? The [SDS sheet](http://www.krazyglue.com/docs/default-source/MSDS-Sheets/skg0583.pdf?sfvrsn=8) for "Krazy Glue" suggests Krazy glue is cyanoacrylate. Is Crazy glue the same thing?

Comment: Yep, that's the stuff, krazy (had to do it twice) what that spell cheker (did it once) doesn't have in its diktionary (had to do it twice) & korrects (had to do it twice) for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to make a repair to a glass surface and not be able to detect the damaged outline.

If you are lucky the glass top when damaged produced a "chip" on the underside of the top. If so it will be easier to repair and less noticeable.

For simple and fast repairs use a cyanoacrylate-type glue (other names are "super" and "crazy glue"). Hold the chip in place and consider how it appears. If you still see a fracture line this is how it will look once the glue dries. You will need hand protection for the next steps. Have a strip of masking tape near by and place one drop (no more) onto the glass chip. immediately and with great accuracy place the chip back into its' divot. Hold for several seconds to let the glue harden. Place the tape over the repair for additional support.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest glue as @ZeroOneZero wrote and then use a compound meant to repair car windscreens to fill the remaining gaps. The seal may be invisible at the end.